# Can someone find deleted questions/answers on my account?

Tags: support

I recall asking a question on this forum about why a particular chord progression in a star wars song sounded so good and I thought I had received answers on it.

But after inspecting my account I can't find that question on there. So I assume it must have been deleted at some point.

I think it was regarding asking about chords in this song: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVWr249AUq4

Comment: The accepted answer to the duplicate contains instructions for viewing your deleted questions. (However, I guess I'm not sure if that includes all deletes or only self-deleted. If only the latter, let me know; I'll remove my close vote.)

Comment: So I succeeded in seeing my closed questions but I couldn’t find the question I thought I had asked. So either there’s something I’m not able to see or I didn’t ask it here. I’m not sure which is the case

Comment: You have no deleted questions on Music Stack Exchange.